# I am getting an error when training yolov5

Tags: yolov5

I am trying to train a yolov5 model, but I'm getting an exception error when I try to execute the training module. The error occurs after the model is loaded and when it tries to read the training images. Below is my code and an excerpt of the error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
!python train.py --img 640 --batch 16 --epochs 150 --data pollen_data.yaml --weights yolov5x.pt

Model summary: 567 layers, 86217814 parameters, 86217814 gradients, 204.2 GFLOPs

Transferred 739/745 items from yolov5x.pt
Scaled weight_decay = 0.0005
optimizer: SGD with parameter groups 123 weight (no decay), 126 weight, 126 bias
albumentations: version 1.0.3 required by YOLOv5, but version 0.1.12 is currently installed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/yolov5/utils/datasets.py", line 405, in __init__
    t = t.read().strip().splitlines()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 643, in <module>
    main(opt)
  File "train.py", line 539, in main
    train(opt.hyp, opt, device, callbacks)
  File "train.py", line 227, in train
    prefix=colorstr('train: '), shuffle=True)
  File "/content/yolov5/utils/datasets.py", line 110, in create_dataloader
    prefix=prefix)
  File "/content/yolov5/utils/datasets.py", line 415, in __init__
    raise Exception(f'{prefix}Error loading data from {path}: {e}\nSee {HELP_URL}')
Exception: train: Error loading data from /content/datasets/images/training/im0.jpg: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

1. The training images I have (im0.jpg and im1.jpg) are two large files. The first has dimensions of 9058 x 11185, and the second file is 13385 x 12832. I realize they are not square but I'm assuming that the train.py module will make them square, so it's okay. Is that right?
2. Or could the non-square dimensions be causing the choke?
3. Also, what is the meaning of the exception "error loading data from /content/datasets/images/training/im0.jpg: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using yolov5 for the past 1 month.I must say your error is wierd.
And also, you cant train your model with image size as 12000. By default it should be 640.In your case it might change based on your dataset but i'm quite sure that it wont be 12000.

There is a mistake in your data directory also.

```
--data /content/datasets/annotations/dataset.yaml.txt
```

The data file wont have '.txt' extension. It should be a '.yaml' file. SO change that to

```
--data /content/datasets/annotations/dataset.yaml
```

It should start training after these changes. If not, close this question and  please provide additional information and ask another question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your suggestions did not help but I'm hoping you will bear with me. I could not find how to close this question but I will update my original question.

Comment: Hey, the error ''' 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte ''' is raised when you use a image of format which is not mentioned by default.

Answer (score 0):

the error

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

is raised when you use a image of format which is not mentioned by default.

`IMG_FORMATS = 'bmp', 'dng', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'mpo', 'png', 'tif', 'tiff', 'webp'  # include image suffixes`

But you have mentioned that it is an jpg. I'm confused now. And also if it helps, pls try this solution provided in this issue. [link](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/7092)